# Installation of zbarlight python package for python3.5 in Docker Image

Tags: python, dockerfile, python-3.5

I want to install **zbarlight** python package with Python 3.5 in Docker Image.

Dockerfile was as below

```
FROM python:3.5
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Requirements.txt file is as below

```
Flask==0.12.2
google-cloud==0.27.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
Pillow==4.2.1
numpy==1.13.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2
oauth2client==3.0.0
zbarlight==1.2
```

Error was as below.

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.o -std=c99
src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.c:3:18: fatal error: zbar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <zbar.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Then i installed libzbar-dev locally through

```
sudo apt-get install libzbar-dev
```

Then tried the below commands locally.

```
dpkg -L libzbar-dev
```

Response of the above command

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libzbar-dev
/usr/share/doc/libzbar-dev/copyright
/usr/include
/usr/include/zbar.h
/usr/include/zbar
/usr/include/zbar/Image.h
/usr/include/zbar/Processor.h
/usr/include/zbar/Symbol.h
/usr/include/zbar/Decoder.h
/usr/include/zbar/Scanner.h
/usr/include/zbar/Exception.h
/usr/include/zbar/Video.h
/usr/include/zbar/Window.h
/usr/include/zbar/ImageScanner.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzbar.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/zbar.pc
/usr/share/doc/libzbar-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzbar.so
```

2nd Command

```
ls -l /usr/include/zbar.h
```

Response of the above command.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47339 Jan 28  2016 /usr/include/zbar.h
```

Then added first two lines in the Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -yV libzbar0 libzbar-dev; dpkg -L libzbar-dev; ls -l /usr/include/zbar.h; apt-get update
FROM python:3.5
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Few important Screenshots while building docker image.

[Responses : dpkg -L libzbar-dev & ls -l /usr/include/zbar.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7E3U.png)

[The Final Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J22b9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my Dockerfile as below.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y zbar-tools libzbar-dev python-zbar
RUN dpkg -L libzbar-dev; ls -l /usr/include/zbar.h
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3.5
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN rm /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y python3-venv
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

As I changed my mind of using official Docker image of Python 3.5, I installed Python as a package.
And changed the default python version(modified soft link).